# How can I create enum with default value in postgres

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, enums

I want to create type enum with default value in postgres, yes I have seen previous questions asked on this enum have checked that. or please anyone can suggest me how to accomplish following table structure 
basically i need like this

```
create type status as enum('pending','approved','declined'); //here i want default value to be set as pending.
```

How to accomplish this in table. I am using codeigniter with postgresql. any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default must be in the table definition:

```
CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM ('pending', 'approved', 'declined');

CREATE TABLE t (
    id serial,
    s status default 'pending' -- <==== default value
);

INSERT INTO t(id) VALUES (default) RETURNING *; -- show the result
```

Comment: yes that worked fine thanks frank, but whenever I am trying to insert like this insert into t values(1,2); so it should take approved right?

Comment: No, you get an error because the value 2 isn't a proper status. Try INSERT INTO t VALUES(default), (default); Column id is a serial, a combination of an integer and a sequence that is used by default. If you don't want the sequence, just use an integer and insert the value you need.

Comment: What value will 's' column take if we do not specify ' default 'pending' '? Will it be blank?

Comment: This answer assumes the table is new, and not that the status is a new column on an existing table.

Comment: @rupali317 Yes, it will be `NULL`