# Is there a way to define a PostgreSQL column as an Enum?

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums, dbeaver

In a PostgreSQL DB, imagine you want to add a column called `vehicle_type` and you only want one of the following 3 entries to ever possibly appear: `car`, `truck`, or `motorcycle`.  I thought there would be a way to define this somehow but try a I might, and reading lots of articles, I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Note: I'm working with the DBeaver client but also can run any SQL commands too.

Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, just create a new type, then use that type in your column.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250939/in-postgres-how-do-you-restrict-possible-values-for-a-particular-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create enum with default value in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482064/how-can-i-create-enum-with-default-value-in-postgres)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE TYPE vehicle_type AS ENUM ('car', 'truck', 'motorcycle');
-- add column with default
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN v_type vehicle_type NOT NULL DEFAULT 'car';
```

[Read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html#id-1.5.7.15.5)

Since *" you only want one of the following 3 entries to ever possibly appear"*, also make it NOT NULL.

An `enum` occupies 4 bytes. To keep the disk footprint to a minimum, you *could* alternatively use a [`"char"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE) field instead which  occupies 1 byte;

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
  ADD column v_type2 "char" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'c'
, ADD CONSTRAINT v_type_allowed CHECK (v_type2 IN ('c', 't', 'm'));
```

Upsides: small, fast.
Downsides: Postgres-specific, less readable.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bdeec59353fb7493f0ccdfa258d11094)*

See:

- [How exactly does the one-byte "char" type work in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166167/3684)